# Why is what I type in always saved?

Tags: java, methods

Both Methods I use saves information after I start the code again. I don't understand why this keeps happening and I don't want it to do this. I've been stuck on this for awhile. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.EDIT: This is supposed to reverse a string. I don't want to use StringBuffer or anything like that. Also I want to use a method to reverse it, whether it's a void or not is irrelevant to me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseThree {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static String a = "", b = "", c = "";
static int i = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter Words: ");
        a = input.nextLine();

        reverseMethod();
        //reverseMethod(a);
        System.out.println("Reverse: " + b);

        System.out.print("Try Again?");
        c = input.nextLine();
    } while (c.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
}// end main

/*
 * public static String reverseMethod(String a) {
 *  for (i = a.length() - 1; i>= 0; i--) 
 *     b = b + a.charAt(i); return a; 
 *}
 */

public static void reverseMethod() {
    for (i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        b = b + a.charAt(i);
}

}//end class
```

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of detail: Please put in a little more description about what this code does, what it is supposed to do, more about exactly how it's not working right... Please don't force us to guess. Please check out the [help] section on [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to improve this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saves information? That is because they are fields of the class. Try this:

```
public static void reverseMethod() {
    b = "";
    for (i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        b = b + a.charAt(i);
}
```

By the way, introducing such class variables unless it is really needed, is not good. This is better:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseThree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter Words: ");
            String a = input.nextLine();

            String b = reverseMethod(a);
            System.out.println("Reverse: " + b);

            System.out.print("Try Again?");
            c = input.nextLine();
        } while (c.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
        input.close();
    }

    public static String reverseMethod(String a) {
        String b = "";
        for (i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            b = b + a.charAt(i);
        return b;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why does this solve this? It worked for me but I don't understand why. Can you explain or point me in the direction to find the information myself